# Split strings into multiple strings in android using regex

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I am working on a android project doing things related parsing.suppose I want to split the string into custom format

My String

```
Power supply will be suspended in the following areas on 13-04-15 between 9.00 A.M. to 2.00 P.M. for maintenance work. NUNGAMBAKKAM AREA : Nungambakkam High road(Door no. 33 to 66), Ponnankipuram, Avenue road, New street. TI CYCLE AREA : Cholapuram Main road, Complete Thiruvenkata nagar, Stedford Hospital, Lenin nagar, Teachers colony, Sivananda nagar, Municipal Court and CTH road, Post office, Railway station road, School area, Ramapuram, South park st, Ambattur market, Thasildhar office
```

So I want to split the string into like this

```
Power supply will be suspended in the following areas on 13-04-15 between 9.00 A.M. to 2.00 P.M. for maintenance work
NUNGAMBAKKAM AREA
Nungambakkam High road(Door no. 33 to 66)
Ponnankipuram
Avenue road
...........
Thasildhar office
```

So how can I get this android.help me to get the values

Comment: make use of delimiter instead of space

Comment: What type of delimiter ? I have no idea

Comment: like `;` or `$` or `%` or `&`

Comment: In your input string put a special character that means "new line here"

Comment: @LachlanGoodhew-Cook What like `\n` ?

Comment: More like a special character that won't show up in your input. I would recommend breaking up your input in other ways. If you control the format of the input I'd look at sending it as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=[a-z])\.(?=\s*[A-Z])|[,:]
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/88

For java it would be

```
(?<=[a-z])\\.(?=\\s*[A-Z])|[,:]
```

Comment: i got error when using this     String[] result=subString.split(('?<=[a-z])\.(?=\s*[A-Z])|[,:]');

Comment: @JosSat use `(?<=[a-z])\\.(?=\\s*[A-Z])|[,:]`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is very hard, unless it involves a lot of hardcoding or reconsidering how you store a string. Computers don't work like human brains, so you can only tell them at which character you want it to split or at which index of character.
I'd advise you to use some String which will signal intent to breaking line, like `<LF>` (line feed), then you can use String built-in method:

```
String array[] = string.split("<LF>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split from ***","***(it is easy to implement. there are so many tutorials available online).

Please try to implement by yourself first and if you face problem in implementation then only post question.